# search/replace from script (execute search command from string variable)

Tags: regex, vim

I am scripting search/replace function in vim and have a problem. It should work in visual mode for selected lines.

This works:

```
let b:CON="'<,'>s:[^\t ]:a:e"
vnoremap r :<C-u>execute b:CON
```

But this does not (it should add 'a' after first letter in line):

```
let b:CON="'<,'>s:\([^\t ]\):\1a:e"
vnoremap r :<C-u>execute b:CON
```

So here I just added a group in regex. But it does nothing now. What is wrong here? Same command works fine if I type it in or call it direct via map. Does execute un-escapes some characters in my string? I think it should not.
Extra question: is there some other good way to "execute" command on multiple lines, other than what I use here (C-u).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first only works by accident. For instance you have an actual tab character embedded in `b:CON` instead of `\t` since vim interprets the escape sequences in double quotes strings. The second interprets `\(` as actual `(` and `\1` turns into `^A` (`<c-a>`)

You just need to double escape the slashes.

```
let b:CON="'<,'>s:[^\\t ]:a:e"
let b:CON="'<,'>s:\\([^\\t ]\\):\\1a:e"
```

Or use single quoted strings and escape the single quotes. (where two single quotes equals and escaped single quote.)

```
let b:CON='''<,''>s:[^\t ]:a:e'
let b:CON='''<,''>s:\([^\t ]\):\1a:e'
```

Another way to rewrite the second one would be to use `&` since that represents the whole match

```
let b:CON="'<,'>s:[^\\t ]:&a:e"
```

Or

```
let b:CON='''<,''>s:[^\t ]:&a:e'
```

Take a look at `:help literal-string` for singled quoted strings and `:help expr-string` for double quoted strings.

Comment: Thank you soo much. This work perfectly. May I ask are there other characters that are un-escaped, or is it quote and slash only? Probably you know what part of documentation refers to this, I have looked plenty of docs/tutorial and didn't find anything.

Comment: @MikhailV Read `:help literal-string` and `:help expr-quote`